# Return value depends on argument typescript

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

```js
type options<T extends ZodRawShape> = {
    query?:
      | string
      | URLSearchParams
      | Record<string, string>
      | string[][]
      | undefined;
    method?: "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | undefined;
    body?: BodyInit | null | undefined;
    headers?: HeadersInit | undefined;
    safeParse: ZodObjectArg<T>;
  };

  const sendRequest: <T extends ZodRawShape = any>(
    url: string,
    options?: options<T>
  ) => Promise<
    z.infer<options<T> extends undefined ? any : typeof options.safeParse>
  >
```

I got from typescript

'options' is possibly 'undefined

whereas I use a ternary operator in the return type. Do you have any idea ?

Do have no clue why the inferrence of type doesn not work

Comment: Use `ZodObjectArg<T>` instead of `typeof options.safeParse`